# Change column value when condition is satisfied

Tags: mysql

I have a view with 2 columns :

```
column a     column b
aaa          One
bbb          Two
aaa r3       Three
aaa tr       Four
trr          One
uuu          One
```

What i'm trying to do is to create a new view with the same number of columns but when the value from column a contains aaa then  the value from column b to be  changed to One,for bbb to be Two and for the other values to be the initial one.

I tried doing this with a case statement but it didn't work.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN column a like '%aaa%'
         THEN column b = 'One'
    else column b

...
FROM table;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, try this:

```
SELECT columna,
       CASE 
         WHEN columna like '%aaa%' THEN 'One'
         WHEN columna like '%bbb%' THEN 'Two'
         ELSE columnb
       END columnb
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CASE 
         WHEN a like '%aaa%' THEN 'One'
         ... etc. ...
         ELSE b
    END AS b
...
FROM table;
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.